# Physical RAM consumption for overlapping views of file mappings on Windows

Tags: windows, memory-mapped-files

Assume we have a memory-mapped file of 3 MBytes length. Let’s map this file first in a trivial way: 3 non-overlapped views of 1 MBytes each. In this case the physical RAM consumption will be obviously the total length of the views, that is, 3 MBytes.

But what happens when I used 2 pieces of overlapped views, 2 MBytes of each view, say, the first 2 MBytes from the beginning of the file and the last 2 MBytes, respectively? In this case I get a virtual address space of 2 memory zones, each of them of 2 MBytes, both continuous ones.

I assume that the Windows (especially the Win64) is smart enough to allocate just 3 MBytes of physical RAM in this case, and of course this is the preferred behaviour for my code. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: the views must be coherent - when you have 2 view of the same range of file - data mast be the same in every view. so different virtual addresses from view in both case mapped to the same physical addresses

Comment: Yes, I’m perfectly aware of this aspect, I just want to know surely that no duplicate physical memory is used, even for temporary purposes.

Comment: only mapped to the same physical address can create coherent of different view